# Django - Translate variable before rendering to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am currently using [Django Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/) in order to switch between en/es and viceversa.
And I know that I can use `{%blocktrans%}` in order to translate a variable inside a template. The problem is that I have no access to the template of this particular feature where I need to translate several words.
How do I translate a variable before rendering it into a template?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create language files and translate inside them, please have a look at [How to create language file with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files)

Comment: It works! After that I just needed to use `gettext` as shown on the docs, thanks!